# How to export and import table statistics in Oracle

Tags: oracle

can someone give me a point how to export and import table statistics in Oracle? Thank you

Comment: Did you check the [DBMS_STATS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tgsql/transporting-optimizer-statistics.html#GUID-7F8EE1CC-A173-4B87-AA2E-CD22198EF4F8) package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it depends on what you want.
In oracle exporting table statistics is seen as getting them from the live table statistics and putting them in a separate table. This can be done on various levels and multiple times.

That separate stats table can then be exported using expdp and imported using impdp. It can be helpful to test with production statistics in a test environment or analyze all kinds of oddities.

First create a stat table using
DBMS_STATS.CREATE_STAT_TABLE
Next use the export functions you need from dbms_stats using
DBMS_STATS.EXPORT_TABLE_STAT.

Importing can be done using the import_table_stat procedure.

Full documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS059